# ServiceStack RabbitMqRequestReplyTests leave messages in the DLQ

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

Even though the tests pass, there are quite a few (1 run - 43 dlq) messages in the dead letter queue. Here is an example of some that are correlated.

```
Exchange    mx.servicestack.dlq
Routing Key     mq:Incr.dlq
Redelivered     ○
Properties  
timestamp:  1413840195
message_id: 887b23b8-1243-4e58-9332-0c6cb3af14c6
reply_to:   mq:tmp:916f686feb924d1fb2bfe5b2aa5087d9
priority:   0
delivery_mode:  2
headers:    
Error:  {"ErrorCode":"OperationInterruptedException","Message":"The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=405, text=\"RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'mq:tmp:916f686feb924d1fb2bfe5b2aa5087d9' in vhost '/'\", classId=50, methodId=20, cause=","Errors":[]}
content_type:   application/json
Payload 12 bytes Encoding: string   

{"Value":41}
```

This particular messages was repeated 10 times, is this something that I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was me missing the fact that [this test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Server.Tests/Messaging/MqServerIntroTests.cs#L125) existed! This is what happens when you get old kids.

Answer (score 1):

Something in your program declares queues as exclusive, therefore whatever else tries to access those queues can't, since the queues were declared exclusive